# XeLaTeX and PDFLaTeX give different outputs for Tikz in TeXLive 2019

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pdftex, luatex

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(0,1) node[midway,sloped]{ABCD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code with XeLaTeX, I get the following output:

[image: Tikz output with XeLaTex]

which is wrong but when compile with pdfLaTex or luaLaTeX, I have:

[image]

which is the expected output. I face this problem after update update my TexLive2019 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a regression that has been fixed already in PGF 3.1.4a (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/709).  It just seems that the update has not yet come through to you.

Comment: Alternatively you could just stop using XeTeX, because several things in TikZ are broken in XeTeX (and have always been).

Comment: +1: Nice MWE and problem description.

Comment: @HenriMenke - I have MacTeX2019 with all the latest updates installed on my system, and I can reproduce the OP's issue. Looks to me like the bug(s) fixed in version 3.1.4a of PGF are not, or at least not exclusively, responsible for the issue.

Comment: @Mico Are you sure about that? I get these results: [3.1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgJrQ.png), [3.1.4a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecowx.png).  If you are sure that this is not fixed, please prepare a MWE and open a new issue on GitHub.

Comment: @HenriMenke - My bad! I had erroneously assumed that the hotfix of issue #708 had been pushed to TeXLive in the meantime. (I may have relied too much on your note, posted three days ago, that "The hotfix should trickle through in the next 24h".) I ran `tlmgr` this morning, so I thought I was all up-to-date. However, a belated [!] check reveals that it's still version 3.1.4, not 3.1.4a, of PGF that's installed on my system. My apologies.

Comment: @HenriMenke I saw the announcement but pgf hasn't be installed yet, perhaps you should ask on the texlive list.

Comment: @HenriMenke I know got the update, and with it everything works as expected.

Comment: @HenriMenke Also I update my texlive today and the bug is fixed.